# Turning mesh shapes into shape keys

Tags: drivers

I've imported into Blender a human figure made and rigged in Makehuman. It has about 50 ready-made face shapes but I am unable to control them although their shape-key drivers are visible in the shape-keys tab under object data properties. I need help in how can I turn them into shape-keys that I can animate?

Comment: You make want to try this question on the [MakeHuman forums](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/forum) as few of us here use MakeHuman and even though I use it, I don't recall how to use the shapekey driver.

Answer (score 0):

In the shape keys panel, select the imported mesh shape. Click on the shape key specials button and from the dropdown menu, select "New shape from mix". This creates a shape key that you can manipulate in normal Blender shape key fashion.

[image]

---

Even better, left-click on the imported mesh shape (coloured purple; see image above) and in the drop-down menu, click "delete driver." These leaves you with a ready-made shape key for that particular mesh shape.